# To apply 2 separate filters on 2 separate columns count the number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

```
With Sheets("LifeTimeData")
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="*" & "Deposit", Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    Set r = Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("A:A"))
    Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, r) - 1

    'Worksheets("LifeTimeData").AutoFilterMode = False
    'Sheets("Overview").Range("G16") = Filtred_Rows_Count MsgBox Filtred_Rows_Count
End With
```

Comment: Take look Here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You should include a description on your question explaining what you're trying to achieve and the issue you're facing. Also, format the code on your question for better readability.

Comment: @Tanmoy add a description of your problem, what you are trying to achieve, and upload screen-shots of your data table that you want to Filter with this code

Comment: There is a table ("LifeTimeData") with a separate column for date (column 21) and one for Status. Objective is to filter all data with date from previous month and status "like Deposit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, Filtred_Rows_Count As Long
Dim R As Range

With Sheets("LifeTimeData")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).row
    With .Range("A1:BB" & lastRow)
        .AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
        .AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:="*" & "Deposit"
        Set R = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), .Range("A:A"))
    End With
    Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, R) - 1

    'Worksheets("LifeTimeData").AutoFilterMode = False
    'Sheets("Overview").Range("G16") = Filtred_Rows_Count MsgBox Filtred_Rows_Count
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it. :-)

```
With Sheets("LifeTimeData")
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="*" & Trim("Deposit Received") & "*"
    .Range("A1:BB" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth

    Set r = Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("A:A"))
    Filtred_Rows_Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, r) - 1
    Worksheets("LifeTimeData").AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheets("Overview").Range("H16") = Filtred_Rows_Count
End With
```

Comment: Really? I tested it and failed in filtering by last month date. Make some extensive testing. And try my solution ...

Comment: it'd be fine of yours to give feedbacks to people trying to help you. You didn't oblige them to answer your question, but as a member of SO you may want to show appreciation for their attempts and, once they proved useful, reward them marking their answer as accepted or up-voting their answers. just to prove a member of SO